# startActivityForResult twice

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have two buttons and audio listview, for the first button i use LongClick and startActivityForResult method to get string from another activity for MediaPlayer. But I want to use second button too. I need to use startActivityForResult to get another string for another MediaPlayer, Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String setData, gotArnswer,s,s1;
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        Button b1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button b2 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b2.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                return false;
            }
        });
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                          mMediaPlayer.reset();
                 }
                  mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(s); //using string here
                  mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                 mMediaPlayer.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            }
        });
        b1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activityone.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, 0);
                return false;

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Bundle basket = data.getExtras();
             s = basket.getString("arnswer");

        }
    }
```

And my ListView `onClick()`:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,
                        long id) {
  System.gc();
  music_column_index = musiccursor
    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
  musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
  String filename = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
  Intent person = new Intent();
  Bundle backpack = new Bundle();
  backpack.putString("arnswer", filename);
  person.putExtras(backpack);
  setResult(RESULT_OK, person);
  finish();
}

};
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? I have no idea what you're asking and I suspect I'm not the only one.

Comment: so if i long click on my first button it will start activity for result and listview onClick will send me result which i get like  s = basket.getString("arnswer");  but what i want is if i sstartActivityForResult with button2 to get string from listview and get it like s1 = basket.getString("arnswer");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so basically you need to know about request code which is second parameter u are passing to startActivityForResult. you can use 0 as request code when calling from first button, and 1 as called from second button.

starting activity for result on first button click

```
 startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

starting activity for result on second button click

```
 startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

and you need to add check in onActivityResult(..) method to know which activity is coming back with intent result like given below.

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
           if(requestCode == 0) {
            // handling code of startActivityForResult of first button
           Bundle basket = data.getExtras();
             s = basket.getString("arnswer");
            }
           if(requestCode == 1) {
            // handling code of startActivityForResult of second button
            Bundle basket = data.getExtras();
             s1 = basket.getString("arnswer");
             }

        }
    }
```

Edit:- instead of using 0 and 1 as request code, define constants so can be readable for future.

Comment: Thanks again, it works..but i have one question that you may know I am using (MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
proj, null, null, null); to get all songs from sd card, but MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
proj, null, null, null); is to get all from internal storage..is there any way to merge them?

Comment: No if Uri is different you need to call both ,  you can later add all songs in a List and use them as you want. please try to ask new question for different topic, it gives visibility to more SO members, and u ll get more inputs :), Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your Part of code is useless

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                          mMediaPlayer.reset();
                 }
                  mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(s); //using string here
                  mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                 mMediaPlayer.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            }
        });
```

Only This Part is Working

```
    b1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activityone.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 0);
            return false;

        }
    });
```

Use Two listeners 
One Long Click Listener b1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {})

and other like this
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){})

Then you will be able to get two jobs done with one button